# How to add a specialized sign in button to your app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

There is a new trend that is being utilized on modern web applications, you may have seen it: Login with your facebook account, login with your google account etc... It's actually being used on this very site.

Is there a way to implement this functionality into a rails application? i.e allowing users to login to your application with they're google or facebook credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to look at [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) and it's [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)